# Automatic sending mail alert to users on certain conditions (usage of user name in posts or such)

Tags: search, crawling

I need so send a mail alert to the site users if their name or a relative keyword has been used anywhere in the site, such as in a comment or any other post.This should be done even without tagging the person or the keyword. There are many databases.

Should I crawl the whole site for the keywords or person using timer jobs or any other efficient methods?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using the [Search service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms455094%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and a Timer Job to query for users on a given interval, and check for updates since last run.

Comment: So the configuration is done to crawl the databases on a timer event but isnt it less efficinet if it goes through the same data again and again? it can be filtered is it? and the can the query data altered by the user? like dynamically.

Comment: How about store when you last crawled pr user, then query for content changed after that DateTime?

Comment: Now the database will have many users and users have some specfic keywords in which they should be alerted so how will that affect the crawl?